# How to sync the Host name and Service Name on the tnsnames.ora file using Java and JComboBox and TextField boxes

Tags: java, jcombobox, sid

I am having difficulty trying to get the tnsname.ora file to do the following:

1. I managed to get the JComboBox populated with the data from the service_name
2. My next question is the following:

a.  How does one populate the CORRECT/appropriate host name (e.g. 127.0.0.3) if the specific service_name is selected on the JCombobox.

i.  I know this can be done using a itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie), and I can make it action so populates data whenever one selects a different service name. But the question is HOW or WHAT WAY can one do to do the following:

1. If the service_name equals a certain SID

a.  Then go and get populate the textboxes which store:

i.  Host

ii. Port

iii.    Protocol

I have my own theory how this could be done but do not know how to translate this to Java code:

- If the service_name is selected

  - Go to previous line (4 steps back) where host details is populated
- Populate the host data to the host textbox

  - Go to the previous line where the port is populated
- Populate the port data to port textbox

Answer (score 0):

Isn't TNSNAMES.ORA just a plaintext file? Why not just read it and parse the values you need yourself?

In case you need it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/